# Dygraphs and Angular

Tags: angularjs, dygraphs

I am trying to put together Dygraphs charting library and AngularJS. I have downloaded https://github.com/cdjackson/angular-dygraphs and following the provided example. I was able to have it working with my code. My next step is to assign data to a graph in a callback after data is returned by the server. That is not working well. Have someone any sample of setting up data after it's been returned from the server?

Thanks

```html
<div id="graphdiv" class="col-md-8">
    <ng-dygraphs
        options="graph.options"
        legend="graph.legend"
        data="graph.data"/>
</div>
```

```js
charts.controller('dygraphController', function($scope, chartsService) {
    $scope.graph = {
        data: [
        ],
        options: {
            labels: ["x", "A", "B"]
        },
        legend: {
            series: {
                A: {
                    label: "Series A"
                },
                B: {
                    label: "Series B",
                    format: 3
                }
            }
        }
    };
    // This function is a callback
    function result(data) {
        var base_time = Date.parse("2008/07/01");
        var num = 24 * 0.25 * 365;
        for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            $scope.graph.data.push([new Date(base_time + i * 3600 * 1000),
                        i + 50 * (i % 60),        // line
                        i * (num - i) * 4.0 / num  // parabola
            ]);
        };

    };
});
```

I am getting the following in the Console:

Can't plot empty data set
Heights null 320 320 320 320 0 0
Position [object Object]

Comment: Send your codes pls!

Comment: I have added my code.